# How can I access the setup pages of the router (Asus RT-N53) by wi-fi without an internet connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have an ASUS RT-N53 and each time there is no internet connection I can not access the router setup and configuration pages. If the internet works then, using the address 192.168.1.1, I can access the router.

I want to access the router by wi-fi all the time, even if, for various reasons, the modem is off or it can not establish a link to the ISP. How can I do this? Is it possible?

Comment: This sounds almost like a defective router - there's no reason that the WAN side going down should impact your ability to hit the configuration interface.